# Retrieving variable in onclick with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm trying to submit a JSP page after retrieving a variable from the javascript function with onclick. Is there a way to do that?

Javascript:

```
function sub(str)
{
    alert(str); //To test if I am getting the variable on this function
}
```

JSP contents:

```
  <c:forEach items="${mybean.flag}" var="element">
       <a  href="javascript:sub('${element.CASE}');">${element.CASE}</a> 
     </c:forEach>

    <%String w = request.getParameter("str");


    if(!w.equals("null") {
       Call a java bean to do further manipulations
    }

   %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To submit a form per Javascript, you could do anytime the following:

```
document.forms[0].submit(); // assuming you have at least one Form on your page and want to submit the first one
```

Comment: It wont solve my problem. If you see my foreach, I am actually trying to submit the variable with href. document.forms[0].submit won't carry that variable to the next page. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite get, what you intended. It would be best, if you have a form on your age, which I assume, that you add an <input type="hidden" name="whatever"/> and fill your value in. After the Submit, you have the value available. I thought first, you didn't know how to submit a form dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do pass the variable from onclick using the below code.

Javascript:

function subb(str){

```
alert("Subb" +str);



 form = document.createElement('form');



 form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');



 form.setAttribute('action', 'index.jsp');



myvar = document.createElement('input');



 myvar.setAttribute('name', 'mydata');




 myvar.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');




 myvar.setAttribute('value',str);




 form.appendChild(myvar);




 document.body.appendChild(form);




 form.submit();
```

}

```
   <a  href="javascript:sub('${element.CASE}');">${element.CASE}</a> 




 </c:forEach>





<%String w = request.getParameter("mydata");




if(!w.equals("null") {




   Call a java bean to do further manipulations




}
```

%>